# Spring autowire not working with security configuration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations, autowired, shiro

I get an exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity Error`. I've gone through my code and I think I have all the right annotations. I'm using shiro for authentication and an error is thrown at runtime. This was working before and I don't understand the issues now.

This is my pojo class:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name ="message") 
 public class Message implements Serializable{  
     ...
 }
```

This is my repository:

```
@Repository
@Component(value = "messageRepository")
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    ...
}
```

Snippet of my web security configuration, which throws the error

```
<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager" depends-on="messageRepository">
    <property name="realm" ref="myRealm" />
</bean>
```

This is the error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.shiro.spring.security.interceptor.AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/web-security-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'securityManager' while setting bean property 'securityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class com.mycompany.messages.model.Message
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1387) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:86) ~[spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101) ~[spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87) ~[spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69) ~[spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359) ~[spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322) ~[spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1488) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class com.mycompany.messages.model.Message
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1454) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:285) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class com.mycompany.messages.model.Message
    at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.entity(MetamodelImpl.java:158) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:52) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.1.0.M1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getMetadata(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:61) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.1.0.M1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:145) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.1.0.M1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:83) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.1.0.M1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.1.0.M1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:131) ~[spring-data-commons-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:38) ~[spring-data-commons-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JPA then you have to add your entity to your persistance.xml under `persistence-unit` tag.

Example

```
<persistence-unit name="persistance-unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  ....
  <class>com.mycompany.messages.model.Message</class>
  ....
</persistence-unit>
```

You are annoating the interface you should annoate the implementation class, also `@Repository` and `@Component` are redundant use only `@Repository("messageRepository")`.

```
@Repository("messageRepository")
public class MessageRepositoryImpl implements MessageRepository {
    ...
    //Implement the interface methods
}
```

Comment: I did as you said and this is the error I'm having now:    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.shiro.spring.security.interceptor.AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/web-security-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'securityManager' while setting bean property 'securityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'messageRepository' is defined